# Slow SMB Performance over 10GBE(Write)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, samba, zfs

Does anyone have any experience configuring 10gbe file server with ZFS and SMB?

I have a system up and running but can't for the life of me figure out why the write speeds are so slow.

```
storage@ditstore:/$ iperf -s
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 10.168.0.50 port 5001 connected with 10.168.0.20 port 51809
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  11.4 GBytes  9.75 Gbits/sec
```

Iperf results between client and server

```
storage@ditstore:/dit_share$ dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=4024; sync
4024+0 records in
4024+0 records out
4219469824 bytes (4.2 GB, 3.9 GiB) copied, 7.15359 s, 590 MB/s
```

Local pool speed tested with DD

[AJA Speed Test From Client Over 10gbe (SMB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcJcB.jpg)

If anyone can offer any suggestions about why the write speeds could be going so slow that would be great.

System Info: 
1x Xeon E31225 3.1Ghz. 16GB RAM - NIC Sonnet Presto (mtu 9000 enabled both client and server)
ZFS pool currently 3x 2TB SAS HGST Ultrastar drives

Comment: So iperf is fast, but storing files is slow? -- Slow I/O.

Comment: Only slow over the network, the local pool speeds are around 590mbs.  Client writes are 50mbs but reads are 800mbs

Comment: UPDATE: Testing with Black Magic Speed Test gives 516mb Write 700mb Read. Network Utilisation sits at roughly 7Gb/s. I don't understand why I can't get this whilst writing to the drive via Finder

Comment: @Howard please use MiB when you mean 2^20's (1,048,576's) of 8-bit Bytes, and reserve "mb" for when you mean 10^6's (1,000,000's) of 1-bit bits. Disk and file I/O are traditionally measured in the former, whereas networking and communications speeds are usually measured in the latter. So when you're talking about doing filesystem I/O over a network, you have to be very careful to get your units right and communicate them clearly.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero ....`?  Do you have compression enabled on the ZFS filesystem?  All zeros compresses **really** well...